# reverse engineering bluetooth smart thermostat payload

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to reverse engineering an *ENSTO* "smart" bluetooth thermostat, which i just got installed in the house. The thermostat due to some technical and electrical challenges sometimes got placed at weird positions, so I thought, I am giving this a try, and see how far I can get.

In their official app, i was playing around to generat some log, so I managed to sniff the bluetooth packages, then using *wireshark*, noticated some patterns, but having hard times actually understanding them:

[image]

The first `01` or `00` definitely indicates whether we are increasing or decreasing, but what the rest could be?

Any tips, ideas, and suggestions are welcome!

I am a fullstack engineer, and pretty new all these iot and smarthome things, but trying my best.

```
ACTION  PAYLOAD
INCREASE_BY_5_IN_ONE_HOUR   Value: 01f401143c003c00
DECREASE_BY_5_IN_ONE_HOUR   Value: 00f401143c003c00
    
INCREASE_BY_3_IN_ONE_HOUR   Value: 012c010a3c003c00
DECREASE_BY_3_IN_ONE_HOUR   Value: 002c010a3c003c00
    
INCREASE_BY_1_IN_3_HOURS    Value: 01640014b400b400
DECREASE_BY_1_IN_3_HOURS    Value: 00640014b400b400
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you disassembly the .apk? Try some tools like jadx and localize the function that is capable of parsing bluetooth packets

Comment: @morsisko hmmm, that is an excellent idea! gonan give it a try asap! :) thanks!

Comment: Some useful information [here](https://www.ensto.com/company/newsroom/product-news/smart-heating-with-new-beta-heaters/) about Ensto devices. First... EuroProduct, so assume temp is in Celsius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some elements of answer:
INCREASE_BY_5_IN_ONE_HOUR Value: 01f401143c003c00
01=increase
f401 = 0x1f4=500 times 1/100 of degree (little-endian)
14 =0x14=20  could be a step ?(other case 0x0a=10 )
3c00 =0x3c = 60 minutes
 ( 2 times to check the validity of the frame ?)

more data would be needed to go further

Answer (score 2):

I second the 0x3c00 and 0xb400 as times.

```
>>> struct.pack("<h",60).hex() # 1 hours
'3c00'
>>> struct.pack("<h",180).hex() # 3 hours
'b400'
>>> struct.pack("<h",720).hex() # 12 hours
'd002'
>>> struct.pack("<h",1440).hex() # 24 hours
'a005'
```

Assume the data is all little endian. I suspect the 2x repeat of the time plays some role reporting data for specific ranges, such as between 5pm and 8am in a day.

I think I've found the degrees. I swapped out the f40114 for Bits. I think this is sub-byte format.

```
ACTION  PAYLOAD
INCREASE_BY_5_IN_ONE_HOUR   Value: 01 |f40114| 3c00 3c00    01 | 111 101 00 00000001 00010100 | 3c00 3c00
DECREASE_BY_5_IN_ONE_HOUR   Value: 00 |f40114| 3c00 3c00    00 | 111 101 00 00000001 00010100 | 3c00 3c00
    
INCREASE_BY_3_IN_ONE_HOUR   Value: 01 |2c010a| 3c00 3c00    01 | 001 011 00 00000001 00001010 | 3c00 3c00
DECREASE_BY_3_IN_ONE_HOUR   Value: 00 |2c010a| 3c00 3c00    00 | 001 011 00 00000001 00001010 | 3c00 3c00
    
INCREASE_BY_1_IN_3_HOURS    Value: 01 |640014| b400 b400    01 | 011 001 00 00000000 00010100 | b400 b400
DECREASE_BY_1_IN_3_HOURS    Value: 00 |640014| b400 b400    00 | 011 001 00 00000000 00010100 | b400 b400
                                                                     ^^^Degrees                 ^^^^Minutes
```

So digging on the [Ensto website some useful things](https://www.ensto.com/company/newsroom/product-news/smart-heating-with-new-beta-heaters/)... First, European product, so maybe we can assume the units are in Celsius (at least for this dataset). `Extremely accurate (+/-0.1°C) and completely silent intelligent thermostat` tells us the precision. `The new Beta heaters are equipped with smart electronic thermostats (for 5–30 °C) that can be controlled manually or with Ensto’s Heat Control application (for Android and iOS)` tells us the range. In terms of units this is 50 to 300... which is 250 discrete values, which means we probably have a single byte for temperature. If the OP could tell us the temperatures when these samples were taken, we can see if the temperature is in the message.

Comment: wow! I will post more detailed information and logs about the device, but I feel we are on a good track!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this API-documentation will help (managed to get it from github while enstoflow was active earlier this year). It has all the payloads documented.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ALbayheoGqpcOpPPEXFPCOlECvhd37kC/view?usp=sharing

A snippet from the document:
2.2.5. Boost
Boost gives time in minutes or duration in percentage depending on the mcu mode. Boost offset
(setpoint) is also given and it is between -20 and +20 degrees.

Characteristics UUID ca3c0685-b708-4cd4-a049-5badd10469e7
value BYTE[0] Boost 0=disabled, 1=enabled

BYTE[1-2]: Boost offset int16_t as degrees (20
as 2000 and 21,5 as 2150)
BYTE[3]: Boost offset int8_t percentage
BYTE[4-5]: Boost time set point in minutes
uint8_t
BYTE[6-7]: Boost time in minutes uint8_t,
returns remaining boost time, write does not
have effect

Best regards,
Mika